# Kusto-use Managed Identity for External Table connection

Tags: azure-data-explorer, external-tables

I am trying to create an External Table in Azure Data Explorer using a user-assigned managed identity. The managed identity has been assigned to the cluster and I am using the statement as defined in the documentation

```
.create-or-alter external table external_mylogtable
(mykey:int,mytimestamp:datetime, mycolumn:string)
kind=adl
partition by ( event_date:datetime = bin(mytimestamp, 1d)) 
pathformat = ("event_date="datetime_pattern("yyyy-MM-dd", event_date))  
dataformat=parquet 
( 
   h@'https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path/;managed_identity=c0XYZXYZ-0000-4444-8119-39999z99z9z9'
)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Kusto.Common.Svc.Exceptions.ManagedIdentityNotAllowedByPolicyException
```

Which policy limits the use of managed identities for external tables and why does do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. The policy needs to be altered like this:

````
.alter database mydb policy managed_identity ```
[
  {
    "ObjectId": "c0XYZXYZ-0000-4444-8119-39999z99z9z9",
    "AllowedUsages": "NativeIngestion, ExternalTable"
  }
]```
````

It makes sense to have an admin allowing this. Otherwise any contributor mightstart using the managed identity for some table.

see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-managed-identity-policy-command)